# Check box with 3 states

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a check box with three/four states. See pic below for what i want to achieve. I do have the fa-link working. But, when i click it again instead of not showing fa-link, i want to show an intermediate state with fa-chain-broken.

Here is what  i have so far.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
  appearance: initial;
  outline: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background: #0073C0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f0c1";
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*outline: 1px solid #A9A9A9;*/
}
```

```html
<input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
```

[image]

I do have the fa-link working great. How can i add another state for the fa-chain-broken? javascript is completely ok if CSS is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular checkbox is not capable of doing it. You need to use a flag for this. What I would do is to use a counter flag, that is tied to the element:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".check").data("state", 0).addClass("unchecked");
  $(".multi-checkbox").click(function() {
    var states = ["unchecked", "partial", "checked"];
    var curState = $(this).find(".check").data("state");
    curState++;
    $(this).find(".check").removeClass("unchecked partial checked").addClass(states[curState % states.length]).data("state", curState % states.length);
  });
});
```

```css
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.unchecked i {
  display: none;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.partial i.fa-link {
  display: none;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.checked i.fa-chain-broken {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-checkbox">
  <span class="check">
    <i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
  </span> Check me
</div>
```

I just wrote this snippet for this answer. Let me know if you have any questions. With font awesome, we can do it in a better way.